# How to invert wave svg with css?

Tags: css, svg

I created a hero banner with a background image and an SVG that makes a wave effect overlaying the image.

But I don't know how to invert this wave, I mean to change the sides of the valley and the peak of it.

```
<section class="herobanner"></section>

.herobanner {
    height:100vh; 
    background: 
  url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 54 54" width="2000" ><path d="M0 48 C30 60 38 40 64 48 L64 64 L0 64 Z"  fill="white" stroke="rgba(255,255,255,1)" stroke-width="2"/></svg>') bottom, 
  url('../images/bg/herobanner3.jpg') center/cover;

}
```

I tried changing some numbers in the svg path but I hadn't success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to invert the wave you need to scale it. For example your svg is this:

```css
svg{border:1px solid;transform:scale(-1,1)}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 45 64 19" ><path d="M0 48 C30 60 38 40 64 48 L64 64 L0 64 Z"  stroke="red" /></svg>
```

Alternatively, instead of css you may use presentational attributes:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 45 64 20" ><path transform="scale(-1,1) translate(-64,0)" d="M0 48 C30 60 38 40 64 48 L64 64 L0 64 Z"  stroke="red" /></svg>
```

Ans you can use this SVG element as a background:

```css
.herobanner {
  border:1px solid;
  height:100vh; 
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 45 64 20'%3E%3Cpath transform='scale(-1,1) translate(-64,0)' d='M0 48 C30 60 38 40 64 48 L64 64 L0 64 Z' stroke='red' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section class="herobanner"></section>
```

Or you can transform the `.herobanner`with CSS:

```css
.herobanner {
  border:1px solid;
  height:100vh; 
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 45 64 20'%3E%3Cpath  d='M0 48 C30 60 38 40 64 48 L64 64 L0 64 Z' stroke='red' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:scale(-1,1)
  }
```

```html
<section class="herobanner"></section>
```

Comment: Hey! That worked pretty well! Do you know how could I make this svg become a circle? I mean transform it from a wave to a circle, I want a result like the hero banner of this page: contabilizei.com.br